# Set value when ScriptableObject is created

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

In Unity, is it possible to automatically set a value when a ScriptableObject is created?

In the following example, I have a parent class, `PickupData`, and a child class, `MoneyPickupData`. Whenever an SO of the child class is created (via right-click in the Editor), I would like it to automatically set its `type` to `EPickupType.Money`.

I have tried using the `Awake` method, and I have also tried using the `OnEnable` method.

What I find is that when the SO is created, the value will be set to `Money` for a moment while I type in the name of the SO. But as soon as I press Enter and the SO finishes creating itself, the value gets reset to the first value in the enum.

How can I make it so that the value gets set to `Money` and does not reset?

Parent class

```cs
public class PickupData : ScriptableObject
{
    // The type of this pickup
    public EPickupType type;
}
```

Child class

```cs
public class MoneyPickupData : PickupData
{
    public void Awake()
    {
        // Set the type of this pickup
        type = EPickupType.Money;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer was sort of included in my question. The problem was the *resetting*. So I checked the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.Reset.html) and found the `Reset` method:

> Reset is called when the user hits the Reset button in the Inspector's context menu or **when adding the component the first time**.

This means that the change I make in `Awake` gets overridden by this automatic call to `Reset`.

The solution for me was to change `Awake` to `Reset`.

```cs
public class MoneyPickupData : PickupData
{
    // Reset is called when creating the SO in the Editor
    public void Reset()
    {
        // Set the type of this pickup
        type = EPickupType.Money;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In such a case I would probably rather go for a property and do

```
public abstract class PickupData : ScriptableObject
{
    // The type of this pickup
    public abstract EPickupType type { get; }
}
```

and then

```
public class MoneyPickupData : PickupData
{
    // has to override this
    public override EPickupType type =>  EPickupType.Money;
}
```

so there is actually no way for any Inspector or runtime script to ever change this value.

---

If you really need to support both you could still do it like e.g.

```
public class PickupData : ScriptableObject
{
    [Tooltip("Default type selection, unless the type property is explicitly implemented")]
    [SerializeField] protected EPickupType _type;

    // The type of this pickup
    public virtual EPickupType type => _type;
}

public class MoneyPickupData : PickupData
{
    // doesn't need to override this but can
    public override EPickupType type =>  EPickupType.Money;
}
```

which would of course be slightly uncanny because it would still show up in the Inspector but your derived type could decide to ignore this and overrule the property with a fixed type.